# how to make html class conditional using ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getmsg.length; i++) {
    getMessages += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12'          
data.getmsg[i].user_id_fk == user_id ? 'pull-right user-one' : 'pull-left user-two">'+ data.getmsg[i].reply +'</div></div>'; 
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `()`

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.getmsg.length; i++) {
    getMessages += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 ' + (data.getmsg[i].user_id_fk == user_id ? 'pull-right user-one' : 'pull-left user-two') + '">'+ data.getmsg[i].reply +'</div></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)